# Lipschitz functions are dense in C[0,1], but isn't every function out of C[0,1] Lipschitz?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I've got a question about a topic that has already been discussed here: [In $C[0,1]$ prove that the subset of Lipschitz functions is dense](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/189029/in-c0-1-prove-that-the-subset-of-lipschitz-functions-is-dense)

We have proved that every function in C[a,b] is Lipschitz using the mean value theorem. 
So if I get that right, there is no function in C[0,1] that is not Lipschitz?

Then I am confused how to proof, that Lipschitz functions are dense in C[0,1]

Comment: Are you possibly confusing the fact that every $C^1[a,b]$ function (i.e. every continuously differentiable function on a bounded closed interval) is Lipshitz with the (incorrect) claim, that every $C$ function (i.e. every continuous function) is Lipshitz?

Comment: Ahh, yes, that was the problem, just mistaking the two notations then...thank you!

Answer (score 2):

$x\mapsto \sqrt x$ is in $C[0,1]$, but not Lipschitz.